# Convert functions with joins

Tags: sql, join, to-char

```
SELECT D.DATEVAL,
       D.DAY,
       D.MONVAL,
       D.YEARVAL,
       E.HIREDATE 
  FROM DATE1 D,
       EMP E 
 WHERE TO_DATE('D.DATEVAL-D.MONVAL-D.YEARVAL','DD-MON-YYYY') = E.HIREDATE;
```

Is this subquery correct or not?

My requirement is dispaly date1 table columns along with hiredate, the date1 columns are derived from hiredate by using TO_CHAR() fn. Note:there is no hiredate column in date1 table

Comment: I dont understand the question, can you please provide output of the SQL and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

i assume that DATEVAL is already a date value which is the same as HIREDATE where you can already use to join the tables

```
SELECT D.DATEVAL,
       D.DAY,
       D.MONVAL,
       D.YEARVAL,
       E.HIREDATE 
  FROM DATE1 D
  JOIN EMP E 
    ON TO_DATE('D.DATEVAL','DD-MON-YYYY') = E.HIREDATE;
```

or if you wanted to use the other columns, you can use

```
TO_DATE(D.DAY || '-' || D.MONVAL || '-' D.YEARVAL,'DD-MON-YYYY') = E.HIREDATE;
```

since you used `TO_DATE()`, you may be using Oracle or Postgre in which you can use || (pipe) to concatenate strings

Comment: I think your second approach is more correct.  the first attempt seems problematic `'d.dateval'` in this context appears to be a string (maybe remove the ticks) and it is not in the format 'DD-MON-YYYY'.  If d.dateval is a date as you assumed, you don't need to to_date it; so just d.dateval = e.hiredate;

Comment: CREATE TABLE DATE1

(
DATEVAL NUMBER,

DAYVAL VARCHAR2(3),
MONVAL VARCHAR2(3),

YEARVAL NUMBER(4)

);

   This is table

Comment: @GOVINDREDDY you probably need to show some sample data

Comment: INSERT INTO DATE1 (DATEVAL,DAYVAL,MONVAL,YEARVAL)(SELECT TO_CHAR(HIREDATE,'DD'),TO_CHAR(HIREDATE,'DY'),TO_CHAR
(HIREDATE,'MON'),TO_CHAR(HIREDATE,'YYYY') FROM EMP);        
                                             Likethis i was Inserted the required values  into my table . now i want to display 'DATEVAL,DAYVAL,MONVAL,YEARVAL along with Hiredate....